# Running a command with multiple inputs for many files

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, bioinformatics

I need to run a program using 2 files as input expecting 1 output having 6000 files ranging from abc0000.faa/abc0000.fna to abc6000.faa/abc6000.fna. I also need the output file to have the same file name as the inputs but .paml extension.

This is an example of the full command just for files 0000.

```
./pal2nal.pl abc0000.faa abc0000.fna -codontable 11 -output paml > abc0000.paml
```

Is there a way of running the same command for all files automatically? Something like a for-in-do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over one of the sets of input files (the `.faa` files for example) and generate the other input file and output file names from those:

```
for f in *.faa; do
    ./pal2nal.pl "$f" "${f%.faa}.fna" -codontable 11 -output paml > "${f%.faa}.paml"
done
```

The `${f%word}` syntax removes the shortest trailing component matching `word`.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
seq -w 0 6000
```

will generate all the numbers from 0 to 6000; if a number has fewer than four digits it will be padded with 0s on the left. You can use command substitution to wrap your command in a for-loop:

```
for n in $(seq -w 0 6000) ;do
  ./pal2nal.pl abc$n.faa abc$n.fna -codontable 11 -output paml > abc$n.paml
done
```